# Getting brackets when reading from SQLite database

Tags: android, sql, database, string, sqlite

I'm trying to pull a couple of strings from my SQLite database I have working on my app. However when I try to read the strings all I get is "[][]". This is my string return method

```
public String getData(){
    db = myDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] rows = new String[]{KEY_NAME,KEY_TOPICS};
    Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, rows, null, null, null, null, null);
    String  dun = "";
    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iSubject = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iTopics = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TOPICS);

    ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> t = new ArrayList<String>();


    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        String sS = c.getString(iSubject);
        String tS = c.getString(iTopics);
        s.add(sS);
        t.add(tS);
    }

    dun = "Testsum " + s.toString() + t.toString() + " Checksum";
    c.close();
    return dun;
}
```

Can anyone please suggest why all I'm getting is the "[][]" (and of course the two strings at the start and end of the returned string)?

Answer (score 0):

`s` and `t` are ArrayLists, which are apparently empty. The bracket notation is how such Objects are represented by the `toString()` method. I'm not sure what info you're wanting returned in your String `dun`, but if you would want to show how many items are in each list:

```
dun = "Testsum " + s.size() + " " + t.size() + " Checksum";
```

Comment: Ok so if I wanted to return the strings that are in the columns "KEY_NAME" and "KEY_TOPICS", what would I need to change?

Comment: The way you have it should work, but it will return each List as a single String, which might not be what you want if you need to use/process the items individually. E.g., `t.toString()` might return something like `[Food, Entertainment, Health]`, which would be easier to use if you just returned the List. The Lists are empty, though, so there might be something wrong with your database or the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get data out of `ArrayLists` using .toString(). if you are trying to get the first data of each List you can use this: 
  `dun = "Testsum " + s.get(0) + " " +t.get(0) + " Checksum";`

 or if you want all, use `For` loop instead